# How to bulk insert only new rows in PostreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert, duplicates, bulk

I have list of products (3 million items) without IDs - only titles. But I don't know which titles already exist in DB. New products (about 2.9 million items) must be added into DB. After that I must know ID for each products (new and existing).

Is there the fastest way to do it in PostgreSQL? I can change DB as needed (add default values, add columns etc.).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Import data

[**`COPY`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html) everything to a **temporary staging table** and insert only new titles into your target table.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp(title text);

COPY tmp FROM 'path/to/file.csv';
ANALYZE tmp;

INSERT INTO tbl
SELECT DISTINCT tmp.title
FROM   tmp 
LEFT   JOIN tbl USING (title)
WHERE  tbl.title IS NULL;
```

IDs should be generated automatically with a [`serial`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) column `tbl_id` in `tbl`.

The `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` construct disqualifies already existing titles. `NOT EXISTS` would be another possibility.

`DISTINCT` prevents duplicates in the incoming data in the temporary table `tmp`.

[`ANALYZE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-analyze.html) is useful to make sure the query planner picks a sensible plan, and temporary tables are not analyzed by autovacuum.

Since you have 3 million items, it might pay to raise the setting for `temp_buffer` (*for this session only*):

```
SET temp_buffers = 1000MB;
```

Or however much you can afford and is enough to hold the temp table in RAM, which is much faster. Note: must be done *first* in the session - before any temp objects are created.

#### Retrieve IDs

To see all IDs for the imported data:

```
SELECT tbl.tbl_id, tbl.title
FROM   tbl
JOIN   tmp USING (title)
```

In the same session! A temporary table is dropped automatically at the end of the session.

Comment: Is there a different approach that is more performant than this? This is really starting to slow down with ~200k records for me.