# Command to read a file and execute script with psql

Tags: postgresql, bulkinsert, psql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.0.3. I have an Excel spreadsheet with lots of data to load into couple of tables in Windows OS.

I have written the script to get the data from input file and Insert into some 15 tables. This can't be done with COPY or Import. I named the input file as `DATALD`.
I find out the `psql` command `-d` to point the db and `-f` for the script sql. But I need to know the commands how to feed the input file along with the script so that the data gets inserted into the tables..

For example this is what I have done:

```
begin
for emp in (select distinct w_name from DATALD where w_name <> 'w_name') 
--insert in a loop 
INSERT INTO tblemployer( id_employer, employer_name,date_created, created_by) 
  VALUES (employer_id,emp.w_name,now(),'SYSTEM1');
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: You seem to have written an SQL script. How do you imagine data will be imported to Postgres without using `COPY`?

Comment: I dont know.. I thought COPY is for one file to one table.         for example this is what I have done.                             begin
for emp in (select distinct w_name from DATALD where w_name <> 'w_name')     --insert in a loop                                                                                       INSERT INTO tblemployer(
            id_employer, employer_name,date_created, created_by)
    VALUES (employer_id,emp.w_name,now(),'SYSTEM1');

Comment: All of this (and more, like the Postgres version number) should go into the question, not into comments. Click `edit` under your question.

Comment: Consider the formatting aids of SO ...

Comment: "PostgreSQL 9.0.3". Um. http://postgresql.org/support/versioning/ . Update to 9.0.13, you're missing a good three years of fixes.

Comment: *"This can't be done with COPY or Import"*. **Why not?** That's the most sensible first choice.

Answer (score 1):

For an **SQL script** you must ..

- either have the data inlined in your script (in the same file).
- or you need to utilize `COPY` to import the data into Postgres.

I suppose you use a temporary staging table, since the format doesn't seem to fit the target tables. Code example:
[How to bulk insert only new rows in PostreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15834569/how-to-bulk-insert-only-new-rows-in-postresql/15834758#15834758)

There are other options like [`pg_read_file()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE-TABLE). But:

> Use of these functions is restricted to superusers.

Intended for special purposes.